# Array operations?

Tags: java

I want to know if there is something similar to (input==(letters[i]-'c')) that i can use. I know what i type doesn't make sense but i'm trying to create something similar to that. If the user's input is anything in the array but c, then it displays the first message, else if it is c, then it displays the second message. I just want to somehow temporarily exclude c from the array and have the program check all other elements...

```
char []letters={'a','b','c','d'};
//input is user input

for(int i=0;i<letters.length<;i++)
   if(input==(letters[i]-'c'))
   {
     system.out.print("input might be a,b,d but not c");
   }
   else if(input=='c')
   {
     system.out.print("input is c");
     break;
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Arrays.sort(letters);
if (Arrays.binarySearch(letters, 'c') >= 0) {
    // contains 'c'
} else {
    // doesn't contain 'c'
}
```

Please note that the call to `binarySearch` requires the array to be sorted first, hence `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally what you would do is use a String for text.

```
//input is user input
String letters = "abcd";

if (letters.contains("c")) 
    System.out.print("input contains c");
else
    System.out.print("input doesn't contain c");
```

Comment: You need to negate your check.

Comment: @DavidGrant Good point, I thought it was supposed to be an error message as it doesn't check of any other letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str=Arrays.toString(letters).replaceAll("\\s*\\[*,*\\]*", "");
if(input=='c') {
    system.out.println("input is c");
}
else if(str.contains(""+input)) {
    system.out.print("input might be a,b,d but not c");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could convert it to a list and then use the contains method

This will return true or false. You can use this in your if statement.

eg

```
if (Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c').contains('c')) {
   System.out.print("input might be a,b,d but not c");
}
else {
   System.out.print("input is c");
}
```

(btw your code sample does not compile. `System` should have a capital letter)

Comment: That doesn't work.  Arrays.asList on a char[] produces a single-element list of type char[].

Comment: good point @DavidGrant Thanks. I have just updated the code sample